# I am getting unhandled exception while trying to execute linked list code in visual studio 2010

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
struct node{
int value;
struct node *link;
}*p,**q,*r,*temp;
static int n=0;
void append(struct node **,int);
main(){
append(&p,1);
append(&p,2);
append(&p,3);
append(&p,4);
append(&p,5);
printf("Entered linked list :\n");
//display(p);
getch();
}
void append(struct node **q,int num){
if(n==0){
    struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->value=num;
    temp->link=NULL;
    *q=p;
    n++;
}
else{
    temp=*q;
    while(temp->link!=NULL)
        temp=temp->link;
    r=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    r->value=num;
    r->link=NULL;
    temp->link=r;
    //q=p;
}
}
```

Can somebody please tell me why this message:

> unhandled exception at 0x00fa14ea in linkedlist.c.exe: 0xC000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000004

is coming while running this program in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are accessing data through a NULL pointer. You can tell by the error:

```
Access violation reading location 0x0000004
```

When you get an error saying that you've read a location near NULL, it typically means that you're trying to access a member variable through a NULL pointer. Since the location is 0x4, the offset of that member is likely to be 4 from the start of the object.

The only `struct` you have is this:

```
struct node{
int value;
struct node *link;
};
```

Here, `value` will be at offset 0x0, and `link` will be at offset 0x4, so the error will be somewhere where you are trying to access the `link` member through a NULL pointer.

Comment: @user1615502: Debug! You are using Visual Studio. Put a break point (F9) on the first line of `main` then step through one line at a time using F11 until the error happens. That way you'll know where the error is happening.

Comment: The error is happening at "while(temp->link!=NULL)".How do i correct it?

Comment: @user1615502 So, then it is likely that `temp` evaluates to `NULL` .. how can that be verified/corrected?

Comment: @user1615502: Now just use deduction and work your way back. As @pst says, it seems that `temp` is NULL at that point. So what's causing that? Well, `temp = *q;` so perhaps `q` points to a NULL pointer. What could cause that? Work back until you find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
if(n==0){
    struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->value=num;
    temp->link=NULL;
    *q=p;
    n++;
}
```

you set `*q` to the global pointer `p` (which is `NULL`), you meant

```
*q = temp;
```

of course.